# Get sub-string for major version out of full version string

Tags: python, string, split

I have a script in which I must convert strings of full-versions to just their major parts. For example, I must convert `1.2.3.4.5.6.7` into `1.2`.

Currently I am using this: `'.'.join(s.split('.', 2)[:-1])`

```
>>> s = '1.2.3.4.5.6.7'
>>> '.'.join(s.split('.', 2)[:-1])
'1.2'
```

Which works fine. But it is extremely ugly, I am hoping there is a better way.

**Edit:**

- Performance is an issue, so answers which perform badly (though they might look nice) are not good for me.
- `'.'.join(s.split('.', 2)[:-1])` can also be `'.'.join(s.split('.', 2)[:2])` just as easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regex is not an overkill if you precompile the regex. Thus

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')

# ... later ...

version = '1.2.3.4.5.6.7'

def get_version(s):
    m = pattern.search(s)
    if m:
        return m.group()


print get_version(version)
```

This also will make sure that your version matches the format.

Comment: Note to anyone worrying about performance: this is actually *faster* than a similar function using OP's `split()` approach, by an astonishing 0.01 microseconds (and anyway, if that kind of difference is important, Python is the wrong language for this problem).

Answer (score 2):

Using `regex`:

```
>>> s = '1.2.3.4.5.6.7'
>>> re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)', s).group()
'1.2'
```

#### Timing comparisons:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'^(\d+\.\d+)')

>>> s = '100.21.3.4.5.6.7'
>>> %timeit r.search(s).group()
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 us per loop
>>> %timeit '.'.join(s.split('.')[:2])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 2.32 us per loop
>>> %timeit '.'.join(s.split('.', 2)[:-1])
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 us per loop

>>> s = '100.21.3.4.5.6.7'*100
>>> %timeit r.search(s).group()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.96 us per loop
>>> %timeit '.'.join(s.split('.')[:2])
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.4 us per loop
>>> %timeit '.'.join(s.split('.', 2)[:-1])
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.01 us per loop

>>> s = '100.21.3.4.5.6.7'*1000
>>> %timeit r.search(s).group()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.94 us per loop
>>> %timeit '.'.join(s.split('.')[:2])
1000 loops, best of 3: 314 us per loop
>>> %timeit '.'.join(s.split('.', 2)[:-1])
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.76 us per loop

>>> s = '100.21.3.4.5.6.7'*10000
>>> %timeit r.search(s).group()
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 us per loop
>>> %timeit '.'.join(s.split('.')[:2])
100 loops, best of 3: 5.3 ms per loop        #millisecond 
>>> %timeit '.'.join(s.split('.', 2)[:-1])
10000 loops, best of 3: 104 us per loop
```

`re.findall` based solution is also going to be slow because it requires iteration over the whole string, while `re.search` stops at the first match.

Comment: your regex pattern has unnecessary parentheses, thus it creates another capturing group, wasting performance. Also `\d` will be slow on python 3 because by default it matches characters by their Unicode character class instead of just digits 0-9

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be `'.'.join(s.split('.')[:2])` but it's very similar. I think there's no other *efficient* possibilities: you have to split by dots and then select only the twos first elements.

This solution (or yours, which are the same) are just fine. Just avoid to use regex, it's just overkill for this kind of task.

Comment: Those other solutions offering regex solutions are crazy. Way overkill. This is good.

Comment: I am sorry, but you have added no value by changing -1 to 2. It is the same performance, and the same solution.

Comment: @InbarRose I said it's very similar. Didn't say it was better or worse. And why do you have remove explanation about regex?

Comment: Your answer should be a self-contained world without external references. Thus - should not include a comment to another user on the site about an answer that they gave.

Comment: `'.'.join(s.split('.')[:2])` is even worse than Inbar's solution, you're splitting the string at each `'.'`.

Comment: @MattPavelle How's this good, and how regex is an overkill? See the timing results in my soution.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I responded before the author's edit about efficiency. I believed he was asking if there's a more "readable" way to do it, hence I would have avoided regex.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, looking for the second dot and slicing the string on it:

```
s[:s.index('.', s.index('.')+1)]
```

[It should be about as fast as the `split` and regex versions](http://ideone.com/4EMxfb).